# Which gRPC status output from server when timeouts

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

**Context**: I have a gRPC service (unary API) that calls a SOAP service and returns a grpc status as response.

**Question**: Which grpc.status should return when the call to the SOAP service TIMEOUT?

| grpcClient |----- ? ------| grpcServer |--- TIMEOUT --- | SOAP Service |

Answer (score 1):

DEADLINE_EXCEEDED may be a good option here even though gRPC client may not have set a deadline on the RPC. Since you know that the gRPC server's downstream request failed due to timeout, you can interpret that as deadline exceed situation and send that error to upstream client. The list of codes are here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/statuscodes.md